# Uneven drive size in two way mirrored storage space after replacing a drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, storage-spaces, storage-pool

I have been running a **4x 2TB** array for a 4TB **storage pool** in a two-way mirroring configuration. I am dual booting this machine with **Windows 10 Pro** and an early access version of Windows Server 2019.
After the **failure of one of the 2TB** drives, I replaced it with a **6TB** drive.

I would have thought that such a pool could be expanded to 6TB, but only **33% of the 6TB drive** is used. Is there a way to tell windows to JBOD between the 3x 2TB drives and mirror against the 6TB drive or might I have to re-create the pool to get such a configuration?

I have come across [questions regarding building](https://superuser.com/questions/1242759/how-robust-is-two-way-mirrored-storage-spaces-in-windows-are-there-any-common-g) of an array with different drive sizes, but not to extend it in such a manner.

Comment: you may want to read [Drive symmetry considerations for Storage Spaces Direct](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/storage-spaces/drive-symmetry-considerations)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not fully following how this maps as it talks about discrete servers, rather than for drives in one server. Any clarification would be much appreciated!